# Post en Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, post, realtime-database

**Problema**

Para este proyecto que estoy realizando me gustaría modificar un atributo que ya está en Realtime Database, sin embargo, no logro hacerlo de la manera que me gustaría.

```
postComment(comentario: string, publicacion: number) {  
    return this.http.post(
      'https://####-####-####-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/publicaciones/' + publicacion + '/comentario.json', {
        comentario: comentario
      }
    );
  }
```

Con este fragmento de código lo que consigo es que dentro del atributo `comentario` se guarde una key unica, y dentro de esa key existe otro atributo que se llama `comentario`, en donde aquí si se almacena correctamente la cadena de texto.

**Vista del Realtime Database de Firebase**

Adjunto lo que me muestra en la base de datos al momento de agregar un comentario:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Respuestas esperadas**

> Una vez esto planteado, me gustaría una solución en el que solamente añada al atributo `comentario` la cadena de texto, sin crear nuevas keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No suelo usar el api REST de firebase, pero ojeando la documentación creo que tu problema es que usas el comando post, el cual equivale al comando push de javascript, que tiene el comportamiento que describes. Prueba a usar el comando patch en lugar del comando post

```
return this.http.patch(
  'https://####-####-####-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/publicaciones/' + publicacion + '/comentario.json', {
    comentario: comentario
  }
);
```

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, muchas gracias!